# Jquery disabling auto window scrolling

Tags: jquery

I've created a simply Jquery image transition viewer, and every time a new photo is loaded, the window automatically scrolls up to the top of the new image that just loaded. I am trying to stop this, so that the transition does not interrupt wherever the user may be on the page.

Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var slideShow = function()
{
current_img = $("#current_img"); // <img> element with src to be changed
height_width = 'width="100%" height="100%"';
photos = new Array('images/home_s1.png','images/home_s2.png', 'images/home_s3.png');
setTimeout(function() { current_img.fadeOut('fast', function() { current_img.attr('src', photos[0]); current_img.fadeIn('slow'); }); }, 0);
setTimeout(function() { current_img.fadeOut('fast', function() { current_img.attr('src', photos[1]); current_img.fadeIn('slow'); }); }, 5000);
setTimeout(function() { current_img.fadeOut('fast', function() { current_img.attr('src', photos[2]); current_img.fadeIn('slow'); }); }, 10000);
setTimeout(function() { slideShow(); }, 15000);
}

$("img").ready(slideShow);

});
```

I've tried multiple different ways of manipulating the preventDefault() function, and I have also tried different variations of loading the image (i.e. loading into html() instead of img.attr('src')), but no luck... Any suggestions on the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Did you found this answer?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391833/how-to-prevent-window-from-scrolling-up-on-jquery-slidetoggle?rq=1

All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you seem to be having is that the default implementation of `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` set the `display` property to `none`. That would make the element have 0 height and width, which would cause a sort of jumping effect.

You should use something like `.fadeTo()` instead and don't take the opacity down all the way to 0 when you are switching the image. A value of something like 0.01 would also suffice and won't make jQuery change the `display` attribute to `none`.

Here's an example of what you need to do inside your `setTimeout` callback:

```
setTimeout( function() { 
    current_img.fadeTo( 'fast', 0.01, function() { 
        current_img.attr('src', photos[0]); 
        current_img.fadeTo('slow', 1); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Worked very nicely! I haven't used the fadeTo function before. Thanks!

Comment: @deraad You're welcome :) - P.S., if the problem is solved, you should mark this answer as accepted.